# Horizontally overflowing div boxes with scroll

Tags: html, css

I am trying to achieve the effect that we get with `pre` or some other text content element, it lets the content overflow (unless) we define it to be otherwise.

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa   aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

Like the above. The user has to scroll right or left to reveal the content.

I am trying it with a few `div` boxes but it doesn't seem to work, I've tried float, only instance it works is when I set the inner elements width explicitly to something very large, like 200%

```css
body {
  max-width: 640px;
}

.parent {
  position: relative;
  height: 180px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.inner {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.box {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #222;
  margin: 10px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

example: http://jsbin.com/hurewo/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the float on your boxes and use `display:inline-block;` instead. Then on the parent inner div add `white-space: nowrap;`

```css
body {
  max-width: 640px;
}

.parent {
  position: relative;
  height: 180px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.inner {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.box {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #222;
  margin: 10px;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Exactly this is what I wanted to achieve. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  max-width: 640px;
}

.parent {
  position: relative;
  height: 180px;
  overflow-x: scroll;

}

.inner {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  white-space:nowrap;
}

.box {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #222;
  margin: 10px;
  display:inline-block;

}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey there! Thanks for your answer, and it works perfect, but someone else posted the same solution before you so I accepted theirs as the correct one, nevertheless yours is accurate as well.